# How to know an iOS apps COMPATIBILITY status using Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

As of know my app's compatibility status in AppStore is

"**Compatible with iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch. This app is optimized for iPhone 5.**"

I want to make it compatible with iPhone 6 & 6+. So, i provided all the requirements for making my iOS app to compatible with iPhone 6 & 6+.

My question is:

I want to know my apps compatibility status before sending to AppStore Review process. So, is it possible using Xcode ?

Comment: run in iPhone 6 and 6 plus, then check any issue .

Comment: its not showing any issue. But in AppStore it is still remaining as "Optimized for iPhone 5" only. Not changing to iPhone 6 & 6+.

Comment: what is deployment target ?

Comment: U mean..deployment target??...iOS 6.1

Comment: But i need to support older versions of iOS(6.1+) too.

Comment: Do you have launch images for 6 and 6+ in your app? If not add them, then test your app on the 6/6+ simulator.

Answer (score 1):

first, you can run it in iPhone 6 Plus simulator, if the state bar is very fine, not to become big, then your app is optimized for iPhone 6+.

if your app doesn't optimize for iPhone 6, the screen you see is very terrible, just like small screen was dragged to 2x, like mosaic.

if you have friend who have iPhone 6 Plus, you can run it on the device.

---

for my app, I just delete the launch screen, and add a new one, then Xcode want me to add the launch image of iPhone 6 size, I did this, and run it on simulator, I found the screen didn't mosaic, the control recover the original size, not mosaic, what's more, it become chaos, because the size become small, screen have some blank areas.

then I use auto layout, restrain the control, make them fill all screen, now finish

my english is not very good, you can ask me if you don't understand it